# Image uploads in react native not reaching server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, multer, multipart

I am sending images to a nodeJs server using react native. I have noticed that when i make the request, there is an image file in the request but the response fails saying photos are needed for file upload. The request however works perfectly on postman.
Here is a sample of the code. I am using react native image crop picker to select the image.

```
const choosePhotoFromLibrary = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        cropping: true,
        // multiple: true,
        multiple: false,
        mediaType: 'photo'
    }).then((image) => {
        setPhotos(image.path)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}

getStoreId()
const createProduct = async () => {
    console.log(typeof photos);
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('name', productName)
    data.append('description', description)
    data.append('price', price)
    data.append('category', productCategory)
    data.append('sub-category', productSubCategory)
    data.append('condition', productCondition)
    data.append('photos', photos)
    data.append('type', `Women's wear`)

    console.log(data);
    var config = {
        method: 'post',
        url:url,
        headers: {
            'token': token,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        data: data
    };
    try {
        const product = await axios(config)
        console.log(product);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
data.append('photos', photos)
```

write like this

```
data.append('photos', {
   name: "Example.jpg",
   uri: photos, // This should be something like 'file://...'
   type: "image/jpg" // MIME type of file
})
```

Comment: i tried using this and i get a 503 from the server. the image is now formatted like this`{"name": "IMG_0005.JPG", "type": "image/jpeg", "uri": "/Users/passwordis123/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CA3F4970-38B4-41B4-AD93-30D585472C9D/data/Containers/Data/Application/ED7F2E2D-B33B-4B29-B5D7-5518B7E7DE50/tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/3B62972D-E13A-4C75-85F2-AC40BEA2C6EF.jpg"}`

Comment: in the backend just do `console.log(req.file)` what do you get

Comment: The back end uses multer array to receive the photos field in the form data code shown above

Comment: we have logged the req.file but there are no logs in the server